# menu toolbar overlaping with custom toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a custom created toolbar. But when I run it, the toolbar on the menu (`toolbar_menu.xml`) is overlapping with my custom created toolbar.

**My Custom toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Currency Star"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**My menu:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/swapper"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_swap_vertical_circle_white_18"
        android:title="Swap currency"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

I have set NoActionBar in my manifest and also in `styles.xml`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you setting actionbartitle anywhere in your code?

Comment: I don't think you need the ``TextView``, it seems the app's title and and that ``TextView`` within the ``Toolbar`` both display the same text ``Currency Star``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do.

**1-** Remove `TextView` from inside the Toolbar in XML code and the title will be automatically set for you  (Just you need to set it in java code to what you want)

**2-** If you want to have that `TextView` in XML code then you need to set title to empty in java code like below

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tes);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

       // Here set the title to empty so that the one set automatically app name will be empty 
       setTitle("");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have set, setTitle as empty and it's gone.

Comment: glad to know that it helped you.

Comment: But we can not change that toolbar text color it always black in color in that what will you do ? @Phil

Comment: you can do it in your styles.xml file.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".ACTIVITYNAME"
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

Answer (score 2):

Try this way..
make separate layout for custom toolbar ..

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@null"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:elevation="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserProfile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/user_profile_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

after that include this layout into activity-main..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/amToolbar"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amToolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
     />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

after that put this line..

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

make sure you hide **default actionbar** and also make your change in this code..

i provide only my code..

Answer (score 1):

As i see that you have the same problem with me. Here is my solution for this :

```
//your custom toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = binding.get().toolBarContainer.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //your custom title
    TextView mTitle = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitle.setText(...);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //set displayshowtitle to false to disable title toolbar
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //set navigation if you need
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener((View v) -> onBackClicked());
```